# Проблема с SendMessage

Tags: c++, winapi

Приветствую!

Пытаюсь симулировать нажатие клавиш с помощью SendMessage.
Этот код работает:

```
HWND notepad = FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("1.txt — Блокнот"));
SendMessage(notepad, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
```

А когда я перехожу, собственно, к симуляции нажатия клавиш, т.е.:

```
HWND notepad = FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("1.txt — Блокнот"));
SendMessage(notepad, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
```

, ничего не происходит. Что делать?

Comment: А как вы думаете, во втором примере кому конкретно посылается нажатие клавиши?

Answer (score 1):

Нажатия клавиш симулируют с помощью функции [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx), а не SendMessage.